# Failed to set up Apache for executing PERL file in FreeBSD

Tags: apache-2.4, freebsd, perl, cgi

I've successfully installed perl5 and apache24 in FreeBSD 12. Then I enabled apache24 in `/etc/rc.conf` and see index.html placed in the path `/usr/local/www/apache24/data`. Then in the file `/usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf` I've uncommented the line

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

inside of the `<IfModule mime_module>` and also added `.pl` at the end of the line.

Then I added in the same file the line

```
Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
```

after the line

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLink
```

and restart Apache, but received the error

> Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may

So I added the line without `FollowSymLink` and restart Apache without any errors. But if I follow by the link like `mydomain.com/test.pl` I still see my PERL code displayed as plain text instead of its executing.

My PERL code is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello world!";
```

If I run the code in command line by the command `perl /usr/local/www/apache24/data/test.pl` I receive my two lines i.e. `Content-type: text/html` and `Hello world!`. The file has permissions 755.

What else can I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've uncommented in `httpd.conf` also the line

```
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache24/mod_cgi.so
```

and now the code is executed successfully

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out and thanks for sharing your solution.  It might also be worth noting that the extension of your `AddHandler` is different than the file you are trying to run.

Comment: Yes, I know. As I mentioned in the question, I added `.pl` to `AddHandler` and my file is `test.pl`